# Does New Experience have Search Function?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, content-search-web-part, new-experience

I had google for awhile now and did not manage to find much info regards to Search functionality in New Experience.

Does New Experience have search functionality yet? As I seen request for others for search function.

[image]

If there is search function, how do I add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search does exist on the modern page. You currently dont have any search apps but you do have a search area. Its located on the left hand side just above the menu and below the "office 365" menu. This is also filterable once searched for a given term.

another option would be to create a client app (SPFx) that gives a custom look and feel to search within an app.

Comment: That was hard to find for  me... totally miss that area

Comment: i know typical microsoft moving stuff around from right to left ;) apparently its a better UX for end users and for the look and feel.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the position of the search box? Other than modifying the html.(If that's an option)

Comment: no not possible at the moment

Comment: no problem, any time :) a little read if you like on what you can currently update https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites

Comment: Hi @AliJafer . In modern experience, the search box always redirects to its own Site Collection results page. From Search settings can we change the search center url for modern experience as well as we do for classic pages?